# Selecting if the DB column is empty

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a db that has a column that is empty and not using `NULL`.

How do I select the below column if its empty?

```
$this->db->where("{$this->_table['shop_shipping_rules']}.shop_shipping_rule_name");
```

**Code:**

```
$this->db->or_where("{$this->_table['shop_shipping_rules']}.shop_shipping_rule_country_iso", NULL);
$this->db->or_where("{$this->_table['shop_shipping_rules']}.shop_shipping_rule_country_iso", $country_iso);
$this->db->or_where("{$this->_table['shop_shipping_rules']}.shop_shipping_rule_region_code", $shop_shipping_rule_region_code);
$this->db->where("{$this->_table['shop_shipping_rules']}.shop_shipping_rule_name");
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by, "is empty and not using null".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->where("{$this->_table['shop_shipping_rules']}.shop_shipping_rule_name",'');
```

works for me in Yii and Zend..